# Comparing items within the same set to eachother

Tags: java, list, loops, foreach, set

I have a set of shapes and need to determine which shapes are intersecting which. I currently use two enhanced-`for`-loops (one within the other) but it is not working as expected. It seems to be only comparing a `Shape` with itself. I added a `println()` for debugging purposes and the console output is at the end of this question.

**EDIT:** I've added the code for my interface `Drawables` to show how `intersects(Rectangle rectangle)` and `Shape.getBounds()` are exposed. I've also added my `Collisions` class to show what its methods do.

**EDIT 2:** I can't believe I neglected to mention: `drawables` is a Set! `drawables.add()` behaves like `Set.add()`

**EDIT 8564985294238424:**I never initialize the Set `collisions`. I have fixed this. It now works.

**Class CollisionMonitor** (includes problem method: `Set<Collision> getCollisions()` which is the last in the class)

```
package platformer;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


public class CollisionMonitor
{

private Set<Collision> collisions;
private Set<Drawable> drawables;

public CollisionMonitor(Set<Drawable> drawables)
{
    this.drawables = drawables;
}

public Set<Drawable> getDrawables()
{
    return drawables;
}

public void setDrawables(Collection<? extends Drawable> drawables)
{
    if (drawables != null)
        this.drawables = (new HashSet<Drawable>(drawables));
}

public Set<Drawable> addDrawables(Collection<? extends Drawable> drawables)
{
    if (drawables != null && drawables.isEmpty() == false)
        this.drawables.addAll(drawables);
    return this.drawables;
}

public Set<Collision> getCollisions()    //Problem method!
{
    Set<Drawable> temp = drawables;

    for (Drawable s : drawables)
    {
        for (Drawable ss : temp)
        {
            System.out.println(s + ", " + ss);
            /*if (s.intersects(ss.getBounds()))
            {
                collisions.add(new Collision(s, ss));
            }*/
        }
    }

    return collisions;
}

}
```

**Interface Drawable:**

```
public interface Drawable extends Shape
{
    Color color = new Color(0, 0, 0);

    public Color getColor();
}
```

**Class Collision**

```
public class Collision
{

    Drawable drawable1, drawable2;

    public Collision(Drawable drawable1, Drawable drawable2)
    {
        this.drawable1 = drawable1;
        this.drawable2 = drawable2;
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Bullet@26dea769, platformer.Bullet@26dea769
platformer.Bullet@f1e9457d, platformer.Bullet@f1e9457d
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Bullet@11bd2f5a, platformer.Bullet@11bd2f5a
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Bullet@70a511a, platformer.Bullet@70a511a
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Enemy@660de2f0, platformer.Enemy@660de2f0
platformer.Bullet@6ada16bc, platformer.Bullet@6ada16bc
platformer.Bullet@6ba127e8, platformer.Bullet@6ba127e8
```

Comment: Are you sure the `System.out.println` wasn't inside the `if`-statement when you got that console output? Maybe you should verify it.

Comment: @Lonenebula Yes, I am. In fact, I at one point had a `println("test")` inside the `if` statement to see if it ever made it to that point. It did not

Comment: What does System.out.println print? Please show us.

Comment: @xagyg It's in the main post, but I suppose I can link you here as well. http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=htPu2Sq9

Comment: Do ANY of the functions modify drawables (via s or ss)?

Comment: There is definitely something wrong, there are 32 lines in that output. It should contain the amount of items in the drawables squared

Comment: Does anything in here modify drawables? `if (s.intersects(ss.getBounds()))
            {
                collisions.add(new Collision(s, ss));
            }`

Comment: @RahulBobhate That isn't my problem, the problem has to do with the fact that it is only comparing a `drawable` with itself, and not the rest of them

Comment: @BrianC. thanks for adding the output to the post. Now I want to see the output without the `if` block - please.

Comment: @xagyg No, it simply adds the intersecting objects to a list that will later be checked by my main method

Comment: @xagyg What the heck that seemed to fix it. I don't have a clue why. Updating main post with newfound information. Excerpt of new console output: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uQuRAiFd.

Comment: So I would say that down in those methods in the `if` block the list is getting modified - we need to see that code, in `intersects`, `getBounds`, and `collisions.add`.

Comment: @xagyg `intersects` and `getBounds` are functions of the `Shape` class in the Java standard library. All my `drawables` implement `Shape` at some point. Updating the main post with my code

Comment: What does `collisions.add` do? What about `new Collision`? Show code if you can.

Comment: @xagyg Main post now shows my other code

Comment: Thanks! And `collisions` is simply a set or list? Nothing to do with `drawables`? And `drawables` isn't based on anything to do with `collisions`?

Comment: @xagyg I will add the rest of the class `CollisionMonitor` where the original problem was in, this should clear some things up. EDIT: added

Comment: Still can't see it yet, but can you try commenting out ONLY the `collisions.add` line and see if it also works with that. Narrowing it down.

Comment: Set<Collision> collisions is never initialized. It needs to be initialized in the constructor of CollisionMonitor.

Answer (score 0):

`temp` isn't any different to `drawables`. It's pointing to the same object.

If you want to exlude the exact same element use:

```
for (Drawable s : drawables)
{
    for (Drawable ss : temp)
    {
        if (s == ss) continue;  // don't compare the object to itself
```

Comment: @xagyg My problem is that it doesn't seem to be iterating through each element in the set. I know they are the same, they originally were both referred to as `drawables` but I changed it to see if it made any difference.

Comment: Please remove this block of code and show the output ...            `if (s.intersects(ss.getBounds()))
            {
                collisions.add(new Collision(s, ss));`. I just want to see what the loop does.
            }`

Comment: `Set<Collision> collisions` is never initialized. It needs to be initialized in the constructor of `CollisionMonitor`.